# Rails 5 Register nested attributes has_many through association with n+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a problem with my small app build in Rails 5.

The project have only 4 tables: User, Custom, Contact, ContactCustom

The idea is an User register his customs fields and when he is going to add new contacts, the form should show the customs of the User logged in.

My problem is when I try to register a new contact with the customs of the user logged in, I have a n+1 inserting a nil register in ContactCustom table and don't catch the custom_id that I pass with a hidden_field.

My models are like this:

```
class Custom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :kind
  has_many :contact_customs

  has_many :contacts, through: :contact_customs
end

class ContactCustom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact, optional: true
  belongs_to :custom, optional: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom
end

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :contact_customs
  has_many :customs, through: :contact_customs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_customs
end
```

and here my contact_controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_user_and_custom, only: [ :new, :create, :edit ]

  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
    @contact.contact_customs.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.contact_customs.build
    #binding pry

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_user_and_custom
      @user = current_user
      @usercustom = Custom.where(user_id: @user)
    end

    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:email, :name, :user_id, 
        contact_customs_attributes: [ :id, :value, :custom_id, custom_attributes: [] ])
    end
end
```

and here is my form ... I think that I made something wrong with the each loop:

```
<% @usercustom.each do |c| %>  
      <%= f.fields_for :contact_customs do |cc| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= cc.label :value, c.name %>
            <%= cc.text_field :value %>
        </div>

        <%= cc.fields_for :custom do |custom| %>
              <%= custom.text_field :id, value: c.id %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I don't know how to show how many custom fields as necessary without this loop and my query ~> @usercustom = Custom.where(user_id: @user) is registering one more nil record(n+1).

Here is the log message when I submit the contact form with only one custom record at Custom table:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-17 09:14:02 -0300
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nIlwxH4Ua8DjAKkMpGh8B7nxwYf6gy1Fhkdh1PaMtSANx5sB6YaOKbBUekQ4M3KP56WuHgsX31iHq2lj4+fEwA==", "contact"=>{"email"=>"test@test", "name"=>"name test", "user_id"=>"1", "contact_customs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"value"=>"custom test"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (108.3ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("email", "name", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test@test"], ["name", "name test"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", 2017-03-17 12:14:02 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-17 12:14:02 UTC]]
  SQL (7.7ms)  INSERT INTO "contact_customs" ("value", "contact_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["value", "custom test"], ["contact_id", 3], ["created_at", 2017-03-17 12:14:02 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-17 12:14:02 UTC]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "contact_customs" ("contact_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["contact_id", 3], ["created_at", 2017-03-17 12:14:02 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-17 12:14:02 UTC]]
   (36.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contacts/3
Completed 302 Found in 176ms (ActiveRecord: 154.5ms)
```

Comment: Ok, just one doubt. shouldt you be selecting `@usercustom = Custom.where(user_id: @user.id)`? It is just a doubt. Then how many entries does @usercustom have and how many should they be? Could you include the value retrieved from `@usercustom` and the values that should be retrieved from `customs`. So as my understanding hear your problem is just the query `@usercustom = Custom.where(user_id : @user)` that retrieves one additional value that is equal to `nil`. Maybe you have this value in the `customs` table?

Comment: Fabrizio I edited the post with the log message when I submit the contacts/new form with only one record on Custom table.

Comment: I posted the solution to your problem and updated it, please read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment or remove `@contact.contact_customs.build` from you `create` action. That is the reason you have an N+1 contact_customs with all the fields = nil.

When you do `@contact = Contact.new(contact_params)` you create a `@contact` that should look like this:

```
@contact = Contact.new(:email => contact_params[:email], :name => contact_params[:name], ..etc..., :custom_attributes => contact_customs_attributes: [ :id, :value, :custom_id, custom_attributes: [] ])
```

With that you have a `@contact` object instantiated  and as array:

```
@contact.contact_customs = [ first_contact_custom => [firstvalue, secondvalue], second_contact_custom => [firstvalue, secondvalue]]
```

The following:

```
@contact.contact_customs.build
```

is like doing

```
@custom = Custom.new()
@contact.customs << @custom
```

Which will append that `@custom` entry with all fields = `nil` in the join table `contact_customs`.

```
@contact.contact_customs = [ first_contact_custom => [firstvalue, secondvalue], second_contact_custom => [firstvalue, secondvalue], second_contact_custom => [nil, nil] ]
```

So try remove the following line

```
@contact.contact_customs.build
```

The only place where you need that line is in the `new` action, because you need those fields instantiated for the form.